# Is there a way to force Protocol Buffer to use the constant field size?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a file with constant sized (or so I hoped) protobuf messages defined here:

```
message FrameData {
    required int32 index = 1;
    required bytes timeStamp = 2;
    required int32 timeStampSize = 3;
    required bytes frame = 4;
    required int32 frameSize = 5;
}
```

The file contains hundreds protobuf messages, and all the frames should always be the same size. When I load the file, however, I noticed that I sometimes get corrupted data, usually when `index` has a wide dynamic range.

Protobuf shrinks the data as much as possible, packing ints based on their value - I suspect that it causes my `FrameData` objects to have slightly different sizes.

Is there a way to force protobuf to use a constant field size? Specifically for int32?

(Another option is to use `bytes` type for all fields, but I'd like to avoid that)

Comment: I can't understand, the "other side" of protocol transmission is parsed "manually"?

Comment: Yes. The messages are saved to a file, and the other side reads from that file. Protobuf consumes the stream it reads from, so you need to read manually each Protobuf message and parse it with protobuf. Not the purest of uses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the integer to have fixed length, you can use the corresponding fixed size integer type: `int32` -> `sfixed32`, `uint32` -> `fixed32`, and so on.

However, I don't think it's a good idea to 'guess' the length of the serialized protobuf message. Instead, you should also save the length in your file. For example:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("data", "w");
FrameData frame;
string serialized;
frame.SerializeToString(&serialized);
// write length first
size_t length = serialized.size();
fwrite(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&length), sizeof(length), 1, fp);
// then write the serialized data
fwrite(serialized.c_str(), 1, serialized.size(), fp);
// write other protobuf messages
```

When parsing the file:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("data", "r");
size_t length = 0;
// read length first
fread(&length, sizeof(length), 1, fp);
// then read serialized data
char *buf = new char[length];
fread(buf, length, 1, fp);
// Parse protobuf
FrameData frame;
frame.ParseFromArray(buf, length);
// read other messages.
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I am saving the size actually, but it changes for every frame as the frame index value changes, and therefore its size!